python3 venv - how to sync ansible_python_interpreter for playbooks that mix connection:local and target system
I'm running ansible playbooks in python venv
My playbooks often involve a mix of cloud infrastructure (AWS) and system engineering. I have configured them to run cloud infrastructure tasks with connection: local - this is to minimize access rights required on the target system.
However since using venv I have a conflict in regards to the ansible_python_interpreter location:

on the target system they tend to be in a "default" location /usr/bin/python3 - I am not 100% sure if this is hard coded in ansible, or stored in a PATH variable
on my local system I assume they are defined by

home = /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.12.5
executable = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12
command = /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.12/bin/python3.12 -m venv /Users/jd/projects/mgr2/ansible

Because of this, I cannot run a mixed playbook, either I need add
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /Users/jd/projects/mgr2/ansible/bin/python3

to my playbook to run local tasks or remove this line to run target system tasks.
I'm looking for a way to have python3 in the PATH variable, depending on which venv I am sourcing.

I had a similar problem, and I resolved it with interpreter fallback which can use a list of locations (attempted in order) unlike the interpreter config which is just a single path.
In your inventory set this variable:
...
  ...
    ansible_python_interpreter_fallback:
    - /Users/jd/projects/mgr2/ansible/bin/python3
    - /usr/bin/python3

Note that you can not do this in the config file, unfortunately, it has to be set in inventory (or by inventory plugin).

I am assuming that you have a playbook like following
- hosts: remote
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch file from remote
      fetch:
        src: /path/to/remote/file
        dest: /path/to/local/directory
        flat: yes

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "/Users/jd/projects/mgr2/ansible/bin/python3"
  tasks:
    - name: Copy file locally
      copy:
        src: /path/to/source/file
        dest: /path/to/destination

    - name: Clone Git repository locally
      git:
        repo: 'https://github.com/example/repo.git'
        dest: /path/to/local/repo

For above example playbook you can set the ansible_python_interpreter in your inventory file based on whether the host is local or remote.
Exampple inventory.yml:
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
      ansible_python_interpreter: "/Users/jd/projects/mgr2/ansible/bin/python3"

    remote:
      ansible_host: remote.host.ip
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3


Can this be combined with a dynamic inventory like from aws?

Yes, you can do that
